# All imported video is green in OpenShot

Tags: nvidia, openshot

Ubuntu 11.10 64bit

NVidia Graphics Card: GeForce GTX 580M/PCI/SSE2

Openshot Version: 1.4.2.1

All imported video has a green tinge, for example, people are green, etc.

All video played back in every other app is fine.

Uninstalled/Re-installed, same issue...

Any ideas? Anyone else had this problem?

Comment: This is a bug of Openshot, not related at all with Ubuntu as it can happen in other ditributions as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Terminal

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openshot.developers/ppa

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install openshot blender

## Software sources, add:

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/sunab/kdenlive-release/ubuntu oneiric main

deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/sunab/kdenlive-release/ubuntu oneiric main

...Then Update/Upgrade

Link: http://www.openshotusers.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=1060

Fixed for anyone else who may have the same issue