# Green filter in video with VLC, Mplayer, Gnome media player

Tags: 12.04, video-player

On Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bits, when I open a video with VLC, Mplayer, Gnome media player there is like a green filter.
There is the same problem when I open a video in the web browser.
This look to be the same symptom than on this post [All imported video is green in OpenShot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114114/all-imported-video-is-green-in-openshot) but I never install Openshot.
Also every think work fine on MS-Win.
Please any idea to fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For vlc try changing your video output to OpenGL (preferences -> video -> output). You should be able to change it also for GStreamer based apps by running `gstreamer-properities` in your terminal.

Comment: Perfect. On my hardware, the `vlc` gave green. Changing the output to OpenGLX worked. As for `gstreamer-properties` command preferences, I had to change the default output plugin from `autodetect` to `X Window System(No Xv)` to make it work with `mplayer`.