# How to solve mkv video problem on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, vlc, totem

I have a problem with playing mkv file on my laptop.
I installed driver and working well.
mkv file is full HD (1080p) and my pc is hd (720p). I opened it on totem. it is screenshot.

[image: http://imagesturk.net/images/2013/02/01/vSxue.png]

i opened also on vlc. but result same :(

[image: http://imagesturk.net/images/2013/02/01/7HJd1.png]

on Windows 7 everything is good playing well. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Try this: [Green filter in video with VLC, Mplayer, Gnome media player](http://askubuntu.com/questions/136990/green-filter-in-video-with-vlc-mplayer-gnome-media-player)

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem once. Try this solution from [Lokal](https://superuser.com/users/16814/lokal) on [Super User](https://superuser.com/a/74983/52341):

> Okay, seems that the HUE is has been set to zero.
>
> Open totem Menu:Edit->Preferences:Display [Reset to defaults] Button
>
> This adjusted everything for me, vlc, mplayer etc.